# How to import RxJS merge?

Tags: angular, rxjs, tslint, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In my Angular (v10) project I can import all kinds of RxJS (v6.6.2) operators like

```
import { debounceTime, filter, map, ... and so on } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

except `merge`. `merge` I import like

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/merge';
```

but I think it's not the proper way doing it. I could also write

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
```

but it's prohibited by a suggested blacklist rule for tslint:

```
"import-blacklist": [true, "rxjs", "rxjs/Rx"]
```

What's the right way importing `merge`?

Comment: That’s an old blacklist..

Comment: I think your blacklist rule is obsolete for rxjs 6. Check out the rxjs v5 to v6 migration guide: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#import-paths

Comment: blacklist is outdated. `import { merge } from 'rxjs';` is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Merge` is not an operator function, it's rather an `Observable` creator function and as such, it should be imported just like `from`, `of` or `forkJoin` (all of which are meant for creating new `Observables` rather than operating on exiting ones)